# Lose focus without interacting with component element in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, lost-focus

I have an element within a border, which I change it's visibility to visible, on the click of a button.
When this button is clicked, and the border element is shown, I am putting the border element as the focused element:

```
        <Border Name="MasterBorder" BorderBrush="#737373" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="6" Margin="19,0,0,-25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="26" Background="#595959" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Hidden" LostFocus="c_LostFocus">
            <Slider Name="Master" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Margin="2" />
        </Border>
```

And the click control is :

```
    Private Sub VolumeControl_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(MainPlayPage, MasterBorder)
    End Sub
```

If I do a GetFocusedElement, this returns the MasterBorder, so I presume this is correct. I have the

```
LostFocus="c_LostFocus"
```

on my button with the following being triggered.

```
Private Sub c_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Lost Focus")
End Sub
```

My issue is, when I open up the control, and it focuses, that all works fine, if I use the control slider, and then click outside the control, it fires the lost focus function. If I do not interact with the slider or border, and click somewhere outside of it to remove focus, my lost focus function does not trigger. Any ideas why this would be?

Additional handler in main window to change focus:

```
Public Sub OnPreviewMouseDownA(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(MainWindow, MainWindow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Does "somewhere outside" means that you click on another focusable control or where are you clicking?

Comment: Anywhere that isn't within that control

Comment: The focus isn't lost until another control is actually focused.

Comment: Why do you want the border to have focus? Why not the slider?

Comment: @HenrikHansen I want the border and all its contents to have focus as a 'control'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LostFocus` event shoud be raised provided that you click on something that actually steals the focus from the `Border`.

For example, clicking on a `TextBlock` won't cause the `LostFocus` event for the Border to get raised whereas clicking on a `Button` or another input control will.

Comment: So I've given my main window focus when there is a click on it, and it still doesn't fire til I've done something with the control

Comment: Show what you have tried? Does it work when you click on a Button outside the focused Border?

Comment: I've added in what I tried, so basically, when anywhere is clicked, it changes to focus on the main window. What I was thinking, is if in the OnPreviewMouseDown, if I could do a hit test to get the element clicked, and if it's a control that I was trying to avoid, do nothing with it, but that wouldn't work either

Comment: @Navvy: The first argument specifies the scope and should be the same in both calls to FocusManager.SetFocusedElement.

Comment: Bearing in mind, the two focus points are on different pages, I guess that doesn't help?

Comment: @Navvy: You should read up on logical focus on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview